# Función sleep en C no ejecuta parada con mpirun

Tags: c, mpi

Estoy utilizando OpenMPI sobre C con un pequeño ejemplo de código como el que sigue:

```
/** Código de ejemplo */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    printf("El rango del proceso es %d\n", rank);
    sleep(30);
    printf("El número de procesos %d\n", size);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

/** Fin de código de ejemplo */
```

Cuando ejecuto con `mpirun -np 5 Ejemplo1.out` (o con `mpiexec`), el programa que ha compilado correctamente no realiza la pausa que le marca el `sleep`. Tampoco la realiza si ejecuto el programa como un archivo ejecutable con `./Ejemplo1.out` sin posibilidad de ejecutar múltiples procesos.

Estoy corriendo el ejemplo en Windows 10 con Ubuntu 20.04 en WSL.

Alguien que le haya podido ocurrir lo mismo?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754288/how-to-sleep-in-mpi#19761647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De SO en inglés: [how to sleep in MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754288/how-to-sleep-in-mpi#19761647)

Puedes simular tu propia función `sleep` usando MPI_WTIME() y esperando manualmente a que pase el tiempo necesario. Dependiendo del escenario (número de cores, nodos, etc.), esto puede no tener ningún efecto en el rendimiento, además de dar el beneficio extra de poder ejecutar algún otro código mientras esperas el siguiente ciclo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero veo que MPI_WTIME() no permite ponerle el tiempo de espera deseado, o al menos, yo no lo he visto. Necesito una pausa para controlar que uno de los procesos que utilizaré en el código genere un numero aleatorio por segundo, por ello estaba probando la funcíón sleep() en el código.

Comment: @JordiBurgosVeiga. Aplica `polling`. O sea, pon el MPI_WTIME() dentro de un ciclo lleve el total del tiempo esperado y que termine cuando supere el tiempo deseado.

Comment: Gracias! Solucionado